# Select data from a database and other database related to the

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
//$find = $this->input->post('val');
$find = 'hello';
```

For example i have two database `data1` & `data2` and `data1` is as:

**ROW1:** 111 | 11 | 1 
**ROW2:** 222 | 22 | 2 
**ROW3:** 333 | 33 | 3 
**ROW4:** 444 | 44 | 4

And in database `data2` is as:

**ROW1:** hi | 234 | 978 
**ROW2:** 4312 | hello | 122

And they show(`select * from ...`) in a `<table></table>` as:

**ROW1:** 111 | 222 | 333 | 444 | hi | 4312 
**ROW2:** 11 | 22 | 33 | 44 | 234 | hello  // i want show only this ROW2 because this ROW have value `hello`
**ROW3:** 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 978 | 122

My try is this that it not right:

```
//$find = $this->input->post('val');
$find = 'hello';
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM array('data1','data2') WHERE name LIKE '%$find%' OR number LIKE '%$find%'")
```

How can done this work with php in two database? (if it don't done with codeigniter how is it without codeigniter?)

Answer (score 0):

What do you want exactly? Where (in which table) is the `name` and `number` fields?
I think you want similar to this:

```
(SELECT * FROM data1 WHERE name LIKE "%$find%") UNION (SELECT * FROM data2 WHERE number LIKE "%$find$")
```

And you can check CI's [Active Record class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html).