# Error: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns, how is fix it?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

What is causes this error? How can fix it?

```
$find = 'hello';
$data = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tour_foreign_residence WHERE name LIKE "%' . $find . '%" UNION SELECT * FROM tour_foreign WHERE name LIKE "%' . $find . '%"');
```

Error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>  Error Number: 1222
>  The used SELECT
>   statements have a different number of columns
>  SELECT * FROM
>   tour_foreign_residence WHERE name LIKE "%hello%" UNION SELECT * FROM
>   tour_foreign WHERE name LIKE "%hello%"
>  Filename:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php
>  Line Number: 330

Comment: Don't use `select *`, specify the columns you want. The columns from the different parts of a `union` must have the same data type and it has to be the same number of columns. If that is not possible to achieve you need to have two separate select statements.

Comment: Please read my post in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800259/select-data-from-a-database-and-other-database-related-to-the did should use from UNION or what? how is it in my query?

Comment: If `$find` is actually any kind of user input, use [prepared statements](http://de3.php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) unless you want to get into SQL injection hell big time.

Comment: I have several database, no a database.

Comment: @Philipp Reichart - Did is your order Example #6 in php.net?

Comment: @AliciaCibrian Yes, example #6 would be applicable to your situtation.

Answer (score 2):

There two main rules for using `UNION` operator:

1. Count and ordering retreived columns should be equal in union queries
2. Type of data in appropriates columns must be compatible

In your case, first rule is ignored.
use `join` operator instead

Comment: Please read my post in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800259/select-data-from-a-database-and-other-database-related-to-the did should use from UNION or what? how is it in my query?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need an [**UNION**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)?

UNION requires that all the queries that you're uniting have the same number of columns in the SELECT clause, so you shouldn't use the *, but esplicitly write the fields you need to query. Also, the clumns need to have the same data type.

Comment: Please read my post in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800259/select-data-from-a-database-and-other-database-related-to-the did should use from UNION or what? how is it in my query?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `SELECT *` in your query. Instead write down the actual column names that you want the get from the database. The column names should be same from both the tables. You currently have a `UNION` and it looks like that tables `tour_foreign_residence` and `tour_foreign` has different columns.

Comment: Please read my post in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800259/select-data-from-a-database-and-other-database-related-to-the did should use from UNION or what? how is it in my query?

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3schools article about UNION operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp):

> Each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same
>   number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types.
>   Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.

Comment: Please read my post in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800259/select-data-from-a-database-and-other-database-related-to-the did should use from UNION or what? how is it in my query?